# About python function return value best practice

Tags: python, coding-style

Suppose I'm writing a function in python, this function can either be success or raise exception.

So which one shall I use:

1. return
2. return True
3. no return

---

Edit:

Thanks for response. In this case I mean to ask if return Value have no further meaning, shall I still do a `return True` or something.

The case I'm working on is to write thrift server-side function, where I hesitated whether to use `void` or `boolean` type in the service api.

Comment: empty `return` is same as no `return`.

Comment: Without any further requirements or conditions, this is clearly a subjective question. Have you researched the options? Have you found any pros/cons yourself?

Comment: Define "success": does it simply perform as is, or does it test something to be True or False? If the former, don't return. Similar to Jakob's answer. Better yet: show us the function.

Comment: Python functions always return something if they finish without exception. The return value is `None` unless you specify otherwise in `return` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like no `return` is needed. From your description, the invocation could look like:

```
try:
    myfunc()
except MyException:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

No need to analyze the return value.

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother returning anything, unless you explicitly specify that the function intends to return something useful.

This way you can assume that everything has succeeded if no exception was thrown,

Answer (score 0):

If a function succeeds or fails return a boolean True or False.

If it causes an error, throw an exception.

If it mutates something don't put a return.